# Failing to connect Oracle SQL developer to Amazon RDS

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, oracle-sqldeveloper, amazon-rds

1. I have modified the Public Access to being, "Publicly accessible" - immediately
2. Here are my Oracle SQL developer connection details. I do not have a tnsnames.ora file linked to the developer
   [image]
3. Here are my aws amazon rds connection screenshot I am using the endpoint as my hostname.
   [image]

Question: In the Oracle SQL developer: Should the Database Type be Amazon from the dropdown instead of oracle. If yes, how do I add that?

Comment: if this is RDS Oracle db, oracle is fine. try the IP address vs the network name, and confirm you can ping it successfully

Comment: I suspect you don't have the proper inbound rules set up in your VPC security group. You are using the default VPC security group, which means you don't have an inbound rule to allow the computer where you have SQL Developer to connect. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/default-custom-security-groups.html